# ADO query causing mdb database to exceed 2GB limit

Tags: delphi, ms-access, jet

I'm using the Delphi code below to replace a table inside an Access database with a big csv file in utf=8 format. The DB is 946MB before I start. Everything is OK until my table reaches a certain size then I get an error. When this happens, the database has exceeded 2GB. I'm guessing maybe the Jet engine is creating an internal copy which is causing the overrun - is there any way of stopping this, or maybe someone could suggest a different method of importing my data which avoids it?

```
function TCSVDatabase.ADOFromCSV(ConStr: string): Boolean;
var
  J, K: Integer;
  S: string;
  SN, DN: string;
  DefDir: string;
  DestDir: string;
  TN: TStringList;
begin
  BeginUpdate;
  Result := False;
  DoProgress(0, 'Initializing...');
  DN := ADOSetConnectionString(ConStr);
  if FileExists(DN) then
  begin
    DestDir := ExtractFilePath(DN);
    TN := TStringList.Create;
    Result := True;
    try
      DefDir := FDefaultPath;
      FDefaultPath := DestDir;
      TN.Assign(ADOGetTableNames);
      for K := 0 to TN.Count - 1 do
      begin
        SN := DestDir + TN[K] + '.csv';
        if FileExists(SN) then
        begin
          DoProgress(0, 'Opening "' + TN[K] + '"...');
          FADOTable.Close;
          while FADOTable.Active do;
          FADOTable.Connection := FADOConnection;
          FADOTable.TableName := TN[K];
          FADOTable.Open;
          if FADOTable.Active then
          begin
            Result := True;
            ADOGetFieldNames;
            FADOQuery.Connection := FADOConnection;
            FADOQuery.Recordset := FADOTable.Recordset;
            FADOQuery.Open;
            DoProgress(0, 'Emptying "' + TN[K] + '"...');
            FADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'DELETE * FROM [' + TN[K] + ']';
            FADOQuery.ExecSQL;
            S := ExtractFilePath(SN);
            SetLength(S, Length(S) - 1);
            try
              DoProgress(0, 'Filling "' + TN[K] + '"...');
              FADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO [' + TN[K] +
                '] SELECT * FROM [' + ExtractFileName(SN) + '] IN "' + S +
                '" "Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited(,);CharacterSet=65001;"';
              FADOQuery.ExecSQL;
            except
              FADOQuery.Connection := nil;
              FADOQuery.Close;
              DoProgress(0, 'SQL error in "' + TN[K] + '"');
{$IFDEF VCL}
              ShowMessage('SQL error in "' + TN[K]);
{$ENDIF}
              Result := False;
              Exit;
            end;
            FADOQuery.Connection := nil;
            FADOQuery.Close;
            for J := 0 to FTemp.Count - 1 do
            begin
              if (FTemp.Codes[J] in [FT_MEMO, FT_WIDEMEMO]) then
              begin
                FADOTable.First;
                while (not FADOTable.EOF) do
                begin
                  S := FADOTable.Fields[J].AsString;
                  if (Pos('_\', S) <> 0) then
                  begin
                    S := StringReplace(S, '_\r\n_', #13#10, [rfReplaceAll]);
                    S := StringReplace(S, '_\r_', #13, [rfReplaceAll]);
                    S := StringReplace(S, '_\n_', #10, [rfReplaceAll]);
                    FADOTable.Edit;
                    FADOTable.Fields[J].AsString := S;
                    FADOTable.Post;
                  end;
                  FADOTable.Next;
                end;
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
        DoProgress(0, '');
      end;
    finally
      FADOTable.Close;
      if Result then
      begin
        DoProgress(0, 'Compacting...');
        CompactDatabase(DN, FADOConnection);
      end;
      FDefaultPath := DefDir;
      TN.Free;
    end;
  end;
  DoProgress(0, '');
  EndUpdate;
end;
```

Comment: What version of Access?

Comment: Switch to another database, you are already close to the limits. Take a look at SQLite with ZeosLib as an alternative

Comment: Your question has no specification about the amount of data that you are reading in from the CSV files. You whole guess about internal copies is only relevant if the total size of the CSV files plus the original 946 MB is (far) smaller then 2 GB. Otherwise you just bump into the 2GB limit that others have answered for. Please [edit] and add the relevant info so that we can distinguish which of the two cases we're dealing with.

Comment: Correct, Jan - I'm trying to add about 40MB so it's practically half the 2GB limit when it goes wrong.

Comment: In case you might be interested: I created a thinnest-as-possible wrapper around salite3.dll https://github.com/stijnsanders/TSQLite

Comment: Look into doing a database compact after the delete statement. If you are truncating an entire table you can free up that space in the mdb file by compacting first.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me is to clear the tables and refill them in two separate passes, with a CompactDatabase in between. Thanks for your suggestions everyone and I hope my solution helps someone else :-)

PS Thanks Sam I just saw your answer after testing my fix and it'a basically what you suggested!

```
function TCSVDatabase.ADOFromCSV(ConStr: string): Boolean;
var
  Err: Cardinal;
  J, K: Integer;
  S: string;
  SN, DN: string;
  DefDir: string;
  DestDir: string;
  TN: TStringList;
begin
  BeginUpdate;
  Result := False;
  DoProgress(0, 'Initializing...');
  DN := ADOSetConnectionString(ConStr);
  if FileExists(DN) then
  begin
    DestDir := ExtractFilePath(DN);
    TN := TStringList.Create;
    Result := True;
    try
      DefDir := FDefaultPath;
      FDefaultPath := DestDir;
      TN.Assign(ADOGetTableNames);
      for K := 0 to TN.Count - 1 do
      begin
        SN := DestDir + TN[K] + '.csv';
        if FileExists(SN) then
        begin
          DoProgress(0, 'Emptying "' + TN[K] + '"...');
          FADOTable.Close;
          while FADOTable.Active do;
          FADOTable.Connection := FADOConnection;
          FADOTable.TableName := TN[K];
          FADOTable.Open;
          if FADOTable.Active then
          begin
            Result := True;
            ADOGetFieldNames;
            FADOQuery.Connection := FADOConnection;
            FADOQuery.Recordset := FADOTable.Recordset;
            FADOQuery.Open;
            FADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'DELETE * FROM [' + TN[K] + ']';
            FADOQuery.ExecSQL;
          end;
        end;
        DoProgress(0, '');
      end;
      DoProgress(0, 'Compacting...');
      CompactDatabase(DN, FADOConnection);
      DN := ADOSetConnectionString(ConStr);
      for K := 0 to TN.Count - 1 do
      begin
        SN := DestDir + TN[K] + '.csv';
        if FileExists(SN) then
        begin
          DoProgress(0, 'Opening "' + TN[K] + '"...');
          FADOTable.Close;
          while FADOTable.Active do;
          FADOTable.Connection := FADOConnection;
          FADOTable.TableName := TN[K];
          FADOTable.Open;
          if FADOTable.Active then
          begin
            Result := True;
            ADOGetFieldNames;
            FADOQuery.Connection := FADOConnection;
            FADOQuery.Recordset := FADOTable.Recordset;
            FADOQuery.Open;
            S := ExtractFilePath(SN);
            SetLength(S, Length(S) - 1);
            try
              DoProgress(0, 'Filling "' + TN[K] + '"...');
              FADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO [' + TN[K] +
                '] SELECT * FROM [' + ExtractFileName(SN) + '] IN "' + S +
                '" "Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited(,);CharacterSet=65001;"';
              FADOQuery.ExecSQL;
            except
              FADOQuery.Connection := nil;
              FADOQuery.Close;
              DoProgress(0, 'Error in "' + TN[K] + '"');
              ShowMessage('Error in "' + TN[K] + '"' );
              Result := False;
              Exit;
            end;
            FADOQuery.Connection := nil;
            FADOQuery.Close;
            for J := 0 to FTemp.Count - 1 do
            begin
              if (FTemp.Codes[J] in [FT_MEMO, FT_WIDEMEMO]) then
              begin
                FADOTable.First;
                while (not FADOTable.EOF) do
                begin
                  S := FADOTable.Fields[J].AsString;
                  if (Pos('_\', S) <> 0) then
                  begin
                    S := StringReplace(S, '_\r\n_', #13#10, [rfReplaceAll]);
                    S := StringReplace(S, '_\r_', #13, [rfReplaceAll]);
                    S := StringReplace(S, '_\n_', #10, [rfReplaceAll]);
                    FADOTable.Edit;
                    FADOTable.Fields[J].AsString := S;
                    FADOTable.Post;
                  end;
                  FADOTable.Next;
                end;
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
        DoProgress(0, '');
      end;
    finally
      FADOTable.Close;
      if Result then
      begin
        DoProgress(0, 'Compacting...');
        CompactDatabase(DN, FADOConnection);
      end;
      FDefaultPath := DefDir;
      TN.Free;
    end;
  end;
  DoProgress(0, '');
  EndUpdate;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the database. From [Access 2007 specifications](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-specifications-2eedf198-6b27-4dc5-ae07-3e1fba6d6c96?CorrelationId=75d79284-9816-456a-8249-a1dbb83f62e2&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

> Access database (.accdb) file size
>
> 2 gigabytes, minus the space needed for system objects
>
> Note   Although the maximum size for a single database file is 2GB,
>   you can work around this limitation by using a split database. A
>   front-end database file can point to thousands of back-end database
>   files, each of which could be as large as 2GB. For more information,
>   see the topic, Split an Access database.

You should also consider to move to another relational database management system(RDBMS) like Oracle,SQL server, FireBird (you name it)

Comment: The database is 946 MB and the data I'm trying to add is about 40MB. So it's almost exactly 1GB in total, which is why I'm guessing that something is temporarily doubling in size when I run my query. The database is the property of a large organisation and I can't change the format.

Comment: @rshotbolt: So you're saying *I don't care what the answer is that you write, as long as it's something I want to hear. Don't give me the facts or documentation.*

Comment: What a ridiculous comment, of course I'm interested in all suggestions. This database is the UK Species Inventory (UKSI) that powers the Natural History Museum species search, and the National Biodiversity Network online recording apps e.g. iRecord, and I am working with their database manager to try and fix this problem. Changing to a new database is not an option.